# addView to an inflated LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-view, layout-inflater

I am trying to add a `Layout` to a `LinaerLayout`. while creating my view for the first time the layout is add nicely which means that the inflate and the addView are working well. but when I click a button to do the process a second time and add the same view another time it works but the view is add on top of the first one.

The Fragment :

```
 // onCreateView, I bind the container with his LinearLayout
 mLnPricing = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.lnPricing);

 //some stuff

 private void createPriceBlock() {

    mParent = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
            R.layout.block_pricing, null);
    //binding some views
    mIbAddPricing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createPriceBlock();
        }
    });
    mLnPricing.addView(mParent,0);
}
```

block_pricing.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

//some text fields

</LinearLayout>
```

main_lauyout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

//some controllers

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnPricing"
        style="@style/addLabels.AppTheme"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />




</ScrollView>
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code but for some weird reason the same code is working on another project.

What I expect: Add the new view at the position 0 and move the other views down.

what I have: The view is add on top of the previews one and a blank space is created below the view

Comment: Its better you go for `CustomAdapter` and `listView` and `custom view`

Comment: mLnPricing.requestLayout();

Comment: @MikeM. thanks you spot it, I really missed to override the orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default orientation for a LinearLayout is horizontal. You've not specified an orientation for the LinearLayout that the new Views are being added to, so the old ones are being pushed off-screen to the right. Add `android:orientation="vertical"` to the `lnPricing` LinearLayout tag.